# Converting Object(DGV value)

Tags: c#, datagridview, casting

I may not be able to explain this that well, so sorry if there's any confusion.

I'm using this .dll here: https://github.com/trydis/FIFA-Ultimate-Team-2014-Toolkit#initialization

There's a class called nation in it that I'm using here: https://github.com/trydis/FIFA-Ultimate-Team-2014-Toolkit/blob/master/UltimateTeam.Toolkit/Parameters/Nation.cs

I need to use one of the nations in a set of params, but I can't get it to work. Here's the code below, that I'm using.

```
                Level leveltest = (Level)Enum.Parse(typeof(Level), dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                Nation nationtest = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value;
                var searchParameters = new PlayerSearchParameters
                {
                    Level = leveltest,
                    Nation = Convert.ToUInt32(nationtest),
                }
```

I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'UltimateTeam.Toolkit.Parameters.Nation'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

I got the param Level to work, but I can't get Nation to work.

All help is really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to cast it to `Nation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the value in that cell is the `Description` of `Nation` class which comes from the base class `SearchParameterBase<uint>`, you can get an instance of a `Nation` with the specified `Description` as follows:

```
Nation nationtest = Nation.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Description == dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value);
```

Comment: I did that and got the unhandled exception "{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'UltimateTeam.Toolkit.Parameters.Nation'."}"

Comment: So it seems that your data is a serialized representation of `Nation' object. What is the string value?

Comment: In the DGV? It's "England" without quotes.

Comment: Now I get "{"Sequence contains no matching element"}" but I think it's because I have "Nation = Convert.ToUInt32(nationtest)," If I don't though I get the error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'UltimateTeam.Toolkit.Parameters.Nation' to 'uint'" where the param is.

Comment: Of course, no need to convert, just do `nationtest.Value`, but in your case just assign the `nationtest` to `Nation` property: `Nation = nationtest`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much, I really appreciate the help you've given me.